# RegExp of flex and actionscript project in flash builder

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, flash

For the same code below:

```
trace(new RegExp("..")("Hello"));
```

In ActionScript Project output:

> /../

But in Flex Project output:

> He

Why?

Comment: How about `.{2}` instead of `..`?

Comment: And also try `trace((new RegExp("..")).exec("Hello"));`.